# php radio buttons submit form issue

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to create a short form.

The user has to type, it's name, it's email address and to choose an answer from 4 options.(radio buttons)

My expectations:
- if the user doesn't specify a name,email address or doesn't choose a radio button(at all) a Error message will appear;
-out of the 4 options(radio button), only one answer is correct and I would like to receive the email  with the user's name and e-mail address, only if the selected radio box is correct;
-if the user is choosing a wrong answer, he will be redirected to a certain html page ("try again artwork" and if the user has chosen the wright only option, he will be redirected to another page.

Please help.
Noob in distress.

I tried to paste the already code but I couldn't paste it.

Comment: What do you want us to do? Code the entire thing for you? [http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html)

Comment: Try and paste it again. You're not going to get any help without it.

Comment: We cant do your homework. Show what you have tried

Comment: copy & paste alternative- `Ctrl + c` = copy and `Ctrl + v` to paste, need to see some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add attribute , " required " to all the input fields so that an error message will be displayed when one is empty!!

To check if the answer is correct, you can use php!

```
$name=$_GET["name"];
$email=$_GET["email"];
$ans=$_GET["ans"];
if($ans=='correct'){
       // you can use mail command here
        header("location:correct.php");
}else{

 header("location:incorrect.php");

 }
```